# How to connect to an Ubuntu VirtualBox virtual machine?

Tags: ubuntu, virtualbox, remote-connection

I have installed Ubuntu 10.10 x64 as a guest OS in one of my virtual machines. My host OS is Windows 7 x64.

I would like to connect to the Ubuntu server instance using a client program or even a simple telnet connection originated from my host.

How do I configure the VirtualBox machine to achieve this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

- Install ssh-server on Ubuntu (`apt-get install ssh-server`)
- Install Putty on your Windows box ( http://www.chiark.greenend.org.uk/~sgtatham/putty/ )
- Connect to your Ubuntu VM using Putty with a non-root user account

---

EDIT:

When attempting this on Ubuntu Server 12.04 it was necessary to use :

```
sudo apt-get install openssh-server
```

Trying to install 'ssh-server' on its own gave you a message saying that it was a virtual package provided by a number of other packages, one of which was openssh-server. Thing have probably changed since the original answer was written.

Comment: I dont need ssh but it's ok even with that. My question was more related to the VirtualBox network configuration of the guest os. Do you think I have to change the network configuration?

Comment: if you can't connect, try changing your connection mode to "bridged"

Comment: Can you ping the guest VM? You can obtain the IP address of the gust VM by opening a terminal and typing "ifconfig". You can then use that IP address from you Windows host to do things like ping. Then you can decide if you want to install something like a telnet (please don't) or ssh server on the guest VM. HTH!

Answer (score 2):

You can pick one of the [networking modes](http://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch06.html#networkingmodes). Bridged networking can be used for this scenario. More details [here](http://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch06.html#idp12173808):

> To enable bridged networking, all you need to do is to open the Settings dialog of a virtual machine, go to the "Network" page and select "Bridged network" in the drop down list for the "Attached to" field. Finally, select desired host interface from the list at the bottom of the page, which contains the physical network interfaces of your systems. On a typical MacBook, for example, this will allow you to select between "en1: AirPort" (which is the wireless interface) and "en0: Ethernet", which represents the interface with a network cable.